# Python: Set interval step of x-Axis dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib, x-axis

I have a .csv file of data of following form

| Date | Company 1 | Company 2 | ... | Company n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | 100 | 20 | ... | 123 |
| 02.01.2021 | 50 | 1 | ... | 455 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 8.11.2021 | 20 | 23 | ... | 122 |

My aim is to choose company x in a Combobox and finally plot it as a graph with

- x-axis = Date

and

- y-axis the values of company x in the column of the .csv-file

In the first step I've a problem with the scale of the x-axis values. My aim is a monthly stepwide but with the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.set_index('Date')

ax = plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Company 1'])
#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
plt.show()
```

I get the result[image]
The x-values overwrite eachother!

I've tried some solution [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-the-datetime-tick-label-frequency-for-matplotlib-plots) but the additional line:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
```

gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xaxis'
```

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots`, `ax.plot(...)`, `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator...`

Comment: thanks this already helped me out

Comment: This isn't working because the `'Date'` column does seem to be a datetime dtype. `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` and then it should be `ax = df.plot(x='Date', figsize=(12, 6))`. If you want subplots, then add `subplots=True`.

Comment: You may need `x_compat=True` if you use `df.plot(...)`.

Comment: My comment should be **...column doesn't seem...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',) 
names = ['Company 1']
features = df[names]
features.index = df['Date']
axs = features.plot(subplots=True)
cursor = MultiCursor(axs[1].get_figure().canvas, axs)
plt.show()
```